# when i insert data in db i get num1 in all column

Tags: php, mysql

i try to creat a table with html and php 
when i insert data into my db i get num 1 like a values in all column 
this my code

```
<html dir="rtl">
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="Nom">الاسم:</label>
  <center><input type="text" name="Nom"></center>
    <label for="Cin">البطاقة الوطنية:</label>
  <center><input type="text" name="Cin"></center>  
  <label for="Tel">الهاتف:</label>
<center>  <input type="text" name="Tel"></center>
  <label for="DATE_donation"> تاريخ التبرع:</label>
  <center><input type="date" name="DATE_donation"></center>
  <center><input type="submit" value="إدخال"></center>
</form>
</html>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "ikhlas";
$con= mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$Name =isset($_POST['Nom']);
$CIN = isset($_POST['Cin']);
$TEL = isset($_POST['Tel']);
$date = isset($_POST['DATE_donation']);
$sql="INSERT INTO persone(Nom, Cin, Tel, DATE_donation) value ('$Name','$CIN','$TEL','$date')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
?>
```

and this my ressult in db[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAik6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sure because you define all variable with $foo = isset($bar) instead of

```
if(isset($bar))
$foo = $bar;
```

Take a look to the doc about SQL injection too: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `isset()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

**Replace to:**

```
if(isset($_POST['إدخال']))
{
    $Name = (!empty($_POST['Nom']))?$_POST['Nom']:""; 
    $CIN = (!empty($_POST['Cin']))?$_POST['Cin']:""; 
    $TEL = (!empty($_POST['Tel']))?$_POST['Tel']:""; 
    $date = (!empty($_POST['DATE_donation']))?$_POST['DATE_donation']:""; 
}
```

Comment: but when i remove isset i get this notice Undefined index in line 23 24 25 26

Comment: You check `empty()` to avoid notice error. See my updated answer!

Comment: thank u bro 
 
and i have an outher problem when i refresh my web page i find new reccord in my db but empty